# MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA returning null, cant get external path

Tags: android, kotlin, file, audio, mediastore

i am trying to get external path throuh content URI, but its return NULL.

```
private fun loadAudioInfo(contentUri: Uri)
    {

        val projection = arrayOf(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA
        )

        applicationContext.contentResolver.query(
            contentUri,
            projection,
            null,
            null,
            null
        )?.use { cursor ->
            val idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)
            val nameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)
            val dataColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)//correctly return column index (2)
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
                val path = cursor.getString(dataColumn)

                val music = MusicAudio(id, name, path)//correctly id, name but path is null
            }
        }

    }
```

How i can get external path to choosen audio file?

Comment: You will not try to get such a path. Just use the content scheme uri.

Comment: I'm assuming you followed an old tutorial to get file paths. `ContentProvider` does not provide file paths even with proper Manifest permissions. You need to use `FileProvider`: [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)

Comment: It is a choosen file @Prajjwal Srivastav and using FileProvider does not make any sense. Dont confuse a new contributer please.

Answer (score 0):

Comment
I tried FileProvider, but i dont uderstand how to make selection Instant correctly.
I tried this:

```
        val imagePath = File(filesDir, "my_audio")
        val newFile = File(imagePath, filename)
        val contentUri = getUriForFile(applicationContext, "com.mydomain.fileprovider", newFile)
        val shareContentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
        shareContentIntent.setClipData(ClipData.newRawUri("", contentUri))
        shareContentIntent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        )
        startActivityForResult(shareContentIntent, 1)
```

but i have no varible: filename
how it would work?

Comment: This looks like a comment/reply rather than an answer.